# Does ChatGPT's limited understanding of novel inputs reveal limitations in language's ability to convey meaning?

Tags: natural-language-processing, open-ai, gpt-3, chatgpt

As a language model, **ChatGPT** generate responses based on patterns they have learned from the data they were trained on. However, it may not always provide a *perfect* or *complete answer* to **novel** or **unexpected inputs**, `indicating that it does not have a genuine understanding of the task or concept at hand`.

> The question then becomes whether inability of **ChatGPT** or other language based AI system to fully understand and respond to **novel** or **unexpected inputs** is a reflection of the **inherent limitations** of language as a medium for conveying meaning and understanding?

Comment: Do you have any examples in mind about your *novel* or *unexpected* inputs? Are they in the sense of purely syntactically technical/tricky or semantically philosophical?

Comment: "No, I don't have any specific examples in mind. I was asking about ChatGPT's general ability to understand novel inputs, regardless of whether they are purely syntactically technical or semantically philosophical in nature. I was wondering if ChatGPT's limited understanding of novel inputs reveals limitations in language's ability to convey meaning more broadly."

Comment: There are people e.g. Yann Le Cun, who believe that language is not enough to provide a LLM or other system a world model. World models / task models / environment  models are important in logic to codify what you know to be able to make novel logical outcomes.